# How to redirect users after posting a comment

Tags: php, url

I want to forward users to a particular URL after posting a comment. I created the post action like this

```
$referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$explode = explode('?posted_on',$referer);
$send_back_url = $explode[0]."?posted_on=".$post_id;
```

This works fine in when the referer URLs are in the following format

- www.xyz.com
- www.xyz.com?posted_on=123

But its not working  when the referer URL is like

- www.xyz.com?post=12

because its trying to forward to

- www.xyz.com?post=12?posted_on=123 .

Actually it should forward to

- www.xyz.com?post=12&posted_on=123

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

- [parse_url](http://php.net/parse_url) to split the URL into its components
- [parse_str](http://php.net/parse_str) to parse the `query` component.